# Jpanel dose not responds to Repaint or revalidate methods

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i have to create a dynamic panels by pass Item Object to the panel it is working fine except when i try to update the object value and try to repaint the content of JPanel by using p.revalidate() ,p.repaint(),panel.revalidate(),panel.repaint(); so please advice what is wrong in my code

```
public class Test {
private HashMap<String,Item> collection = new HashMap<String,Item>();



public Test() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(200, 300);
    frame.add(Container());
    frame.repaint();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Test();
}
private JPanel Container() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    CreateApplicationPanels(panel,"1","A1","A2");
    CreateApplicationPanels(panel,"2","B1","B2");
    return panel;
}

public void CreateApplicationPanels(JPanel panel, String pid,String key1,String key2){
    collection.put(pid, new Item(key1,key2));
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new MigLayout("","","10[]20"));
    p.add(new JLabel(collection.get(pid).getKey1()),"cell 0 0,width 30,split 3");
    p.add(new JLabel(collection.get(pid).getKey2()),"cell 1 0,width 50");
    p.add(new TLabel("",Theam.dark_gray),"cell 6 0, width 400");
    p.setOpaque(false);
    panel.add(p, String.format("cell 0 %s1,grow", pid));
    p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            p.setOpaque(true);
            p.setBackground(Color.decode("#EAF4FF"));
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            p.setOpaque(false);
            p.setBackground(null);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            collection.get(pid).setKey1("Key1 Changes");
            System.out.println(pid+"::>"+collection.get(pid).getKey1());
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
}

class Item{
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    public Item(String key1,String key2) {

        setKey1(key1);
        setKey2(key2);
    }
    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }
    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer view the new updates of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.get(pid).setKey1("Key1 Changes");
```

Changing the value of an Object in a collection has nothing to do with the GUI.

If you want to change the text on the label then you need to change the text on the label.

```
label.setText("some different text");
```

So the trick is to get the reference to the label that you want to update.

I have no ideas what your code is doing. So I can't suggest a general approach. But your current code is updating the key1 value which is assigned to the first label you add to your panel.

So as a quick hack you could to something like:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)p.getComponent(0);
label.setText("some different text");
```

You don't even need to revalidate the panel. The label will automatically repaint() itself.